# How do I make YouTube on Firefox cache the video so it doesn't need to buffer the next time I play it?

Tags: firefox, streaming, firefox-extensions, youtube, video-streaming

Okay just to be clear, I **know** how to disable YouTube's new DASH playback so that's not what I'm asking for.

What I'm trying to do is make videos on YouTube be cached so that if I ever want to watch that video again the next time, it doesn't need to buffer anymore and it will use the local cache stored on Firefox. How do I set it to do that?

Comment: Why not just get a downloader plugin and download the ones you are interested in ?

Answer (score 1):

I use Squid3.x to cache streamable content. While others reported mixed results, I have only one problem with this setup. IF the stream comes via Flash, then I get random dropped streams with the message "Flash has encountered an error". This happens quite rarely, though.

I use this Setup: 
`Desktop <-> RaspberryPi2 <-> RandomRouter <-> StreamingPage`

And the squid instance ran on my Desktop until I got the Pi. Both Situation are working as described and requested.

While I used Squid together with a ramfs for chaching normal pages, to not wear down my Flash on the PI, it is not enough to cache huge amounts of data. Therefor I connected some random USB-platterdrive and gave squid access to 60Gb on this. I just had to enable caching of application/x-shockwave-Flash in squid's conf.

Then I use a proxy selector for FF to connect via the squid instance running either localhost or on the raspberry. There is some more magic possible, than just caching content. This could be interesting for you.

While researching, I found, that on the official squid Homepage, they describe another way to set this up: using a shell script together with squid. I did not try this, but it seems to tackle this task for some people. They also advertize a propietary solution built for videostream-caching. Maybe thats an easy solution there for you.

If you want I could get into details of my simple implementation, else look around on the **[squid's page](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/YouTube)**

I figure, that what I described isnt exactly what you wanted, though. Right now, my cache resides on a remote host in my lan, and is not local to the desktop, which I watch the streams with. But I experience no percievable buffer time, except when the usb-platter is doing IO. Thought I should clarify this.